# out of memory kill process (mysqld)

Tags: mysql, apache, centos, vps

Здравствуйте, есть маленькая машина VPS на DigitalOcean (1lvl, 512 ОЗУ), настроена самостоятельно не опытным сисадмином (я), на ней стоит сайт, посещаемость 4-5к уник в сутки, и примерно раз в день, процесс mysql (mariadb) падает с ошибкой

```
 out of memory kill process (mysqld)
```

Приходится перезагружать апач, и мускул, не подскажите что с этим делать?
 стоит `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16m`

Comment: Очевидно, мускулу не хватает оперативной памяти и ее стоит увеличить (либо заоптимизировать ее потребление). Можно докинуть свапа, но это может сыграть в обратную сторону, замедлив всю работу.

Comment: @etki а можно сделать так чтобы он не убивался? Типа сброс кэша или тд, перезагрузка  ведь помогает. А ещё странно что ограничение innodb не помогает, даже не знаю как можно заставить мускул не потреблять много памяти

Comment: Я не спец по мускулу, но память он забирает не просто так, в текущей конфигурации ему ее явно не хватает.